# How to create a dataset from a fusion sheet in foundry?

Tags: dataset, palantir-foundry, foundry-fusion-sheet

I want to use a fusion sheet for ultimately creating a dictionary in foundry repository.

I want to have a fusion sheet as a input, so that users would enter the values in the fusion sheet, I would then sync the fusion sheet to a data set. How do I do that?

Additionally, after the data set is created, I would want use it to create a dictionary out of that data set. Can anyone help in using the data set to create the dictionary in the repository. any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would advice you to add more precise explanation to your question and maybe more tag words so that people are able to find this question of yours.

Comment: @samuel-liew this question is focused enough for those that know how Palantir-Foundry works technically. I'm willing to answer it if you could vote for reopening. I only count as one vote for reopening :)

Comment: @fmsf go for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two questions here:

Q1 - How do I create a dataset from a fusion sheet, so that a user can use a fusion sheet as input?

Q2 - How do I transform the dataset into a dictionary inside the repo.

Question 2 is very dependent on the technologies that you are using within foundry (PySpark, SQL, etc...) So I would recommend opening a separate question for that in particular with more focused details. I Will answer Question 1.

---

#### How do I create a dataset from a fusion sheet, so that a user can use a fusion sheet as input?

To create a dataset out of a fusion sheet, you'll need to have your fusion have a tabular layout. I.e.: Each column representing one of the inputs. Something like the screenshot below.

[image]

Then click the tab that says Data and below you'll find "Sync To Dataset". Click on it and select the range you want in the popup. In this example we want A1:C2. I'm giving it the name "user_input_dataset"

[image]

Hit add new table and if you have permissions for this, you should get a toaster popup confirming it got created.

[image]

Go back into your folder and next to your spreadsheet you should now have a dataset with the contents of your fusion sheet.

[image]

You can now read this dataset from your repository and do whatever logic you want with it.

---

p.s.:
I don't like to add screenshots because they go out of date as products evolve, but this is hard to answer without them, so I added some. This was correct at time of answering.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I will try this out. thanks again